# Transforming Dictionary<T,U> to Dictionary<T, U.PropertyValue>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm in the process of re-writing some code whilst maintaining the external interface. The method I now need to work on has the following signature:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetClientIdNames()
```

This originally directly returned a backing field, after verifying that it was populating it and doing so if required. There's now a requirement for additional data to be stored, so the backing field is now as follows:

```
private Dictionary<int, Client> _clients;

public struct Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

So, other than simply looping using a `foreach` to construct a `Dictionary<int, string>` from `Dictionary<int, Client>` using the `ClientName` property of the `Client`, how could I perform this transformation on the fly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`Enumerable.ToDictionary`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
var clientNames = _clients.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ClientName);
```

Comment: I would accept your answer *right now*, but I have to wait 10 minutes, apparently. Spot on and if I wasn't in the throes of migrating this module from 2.0 to 3.5, it would've already had the `using System.Linq` at the top of the file and the question would never have been asked. Thankyou! =)